# Count the number of different sections of text that match a regular expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in postgresql. I have an int column "DOC_ID" and a text column "CONTENT".
Each row of the table contains information about the document.

There are sections of text that match the regular expression

`'#[A-Za-z]+:[A-Za-z]+#`. They are different!

For example: #Lot : version# , #Participant : name# and others.

I want for each value that satisfies the regular expression to get a column with the ID of the document in which it occurs. Considering that in one document it can be several times.

Example:
My table:

```
DOC_ID       CONTENT
1            '#Participant : name# cat bear dog #Participant : name# mouse'
2            'cat #Participant : name# bear'
3            'cat #Lot : version# dog'
10           'mouse #Lot : version# cow'
```

Result table

```
TAG                       DOC_ID
#Participant : name#       1
#Participant : name#       1
#Participant : name#       2
#Lot : version#            3
#Lot : version#            10
```

Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: Can you add sample input and desired output?

Comment: example has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `regexp_matches()`:

```sql
select 
    (regexp_matches(content, '#[A-Za-z0-9 №%--,. ]+:[A-Za-z0-9 №%--,. ]+#', 'g'))[1] as tag,
    doc_id
from my_table
```

Read [about the function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) and [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in the documentation.

Test the query in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a444f00621375c15f93361adb859cd6e)